# How can I create back relations with pydantic models

Tags: python, pydantic

I want to make back relation structure with pydantic but I`m getting an exception.
A.update_forward_refs() doesn't help solve the problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 82, in <module>
    a = A(**{"x": 5, "b": {"y": 1}})
  File "pydantic\main.py", line 340, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
  File "pydantic\main.py", line 1077, in pydantic.main.validate_model
  File "pydantic\fields.py", line 860, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.validate
pydantic.errors.ConfigError: field "b" not yet prepared so type is still a ForwardRef, you might need to call A.update_forward_refs().
```

What should I do?

```
from typing import Optional

from pydantic import BaseModel


class A(BaseModel):
    x: int
    b: Optional['B'] = None

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class B(BaseModel):
    y: int
    a: Optional['A'] = None

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


a = A(**{"x": 5, "b": {"y": 1}})

print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You say you tried `A.update_forward_refs()`, but I am guessing you put it in the wrong place because it works fine for me, when I do it. You need to call the method *after* the classes being referenced have been defined, in this case after the definition of `B`, but obviously *before* you actually want to use `A` to parse data.

```py
from typing import Optional

from pydantic import BaseModel


class A(BaseModel):
    x: int
    b: Optional["B"] = None


class B(BaseModel):
    y: int
    a: Optional["A"] = None


A.update_forward_refs()

a = A(**{"x": 5, "b": {"y": 1}})
print(a)
```